# Old values back on pressing escape key twice - Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have used below code to reset my form which clear all textboxes & dropdowns in division where controls are placed.

```
$('#' + divs + ' input[type="text"]').val('');
$('#' + divs + ' select').val('');
```

though it clear values, but on pressing escape key twice values are getting back & applied on form. after little R&D I found its a default behavior of internet explorer. But i want to stop this default behavior without disabling escape key.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit rough, but did you try removing and re-creating the html elements with jQuery instead of resetting the value attribute? If it works, you could also try removing and recreating only the value attribute itself.

Comment: i have tried that its working good with text boxes, on reset i removed value attribute but wht about dropdowns which attribute should i remove ??

Comment: In that case, I think it should be enough to delete and recreate: 1) the select "value" attribute 2) the option previously selected. The jquery selector for point 2 is $('#' + divs + ' select').find('option:selected')